# What does it mean conceptually to multiply a vector with a Matrix on the right?

Tags: linear-algebra

If A=matrix and v=vector, what does it mean to have v*A?

Comment: Note that $(vA)^\top = A^\top v^\top$ so the resulting vector is the image of the $v$ under the transpose of $A$

Comment: What have you learned about linear algebra? Your knowledge on the topic affects what we should answer you.

Comment: I took a linear algebra college course a few years ago and am getting back into learning it as part of a hobby. I don't quite understand what Nitin is saying yet but I will do some searchin.

Comment: Do you know what it is meant by multiplying a vector by a matrix on the left?

Comment: I think so. The matrix transforms the vector. An example would be rotating or skewing the vector.

Comment: Well, this is also transforming the vector, you're just looking at it sideways.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "just looking at it sideways"? Would a visualization of vA be the same as (transpose of A)v?

Comment: Yes, instead of $$\pmatrix{1 & 2 & 3\cr 4 & 5 & 6\cr 7 & 8 & 9} \pmatrix{1\cr 2\cr 3} = \pmatrix{14\cr 32\cr 50}$$ you do $$\pmatrix{1 & 2 & 3} \pmatrix{1 & 4 & 7\cr 2 & 5 & 8\cr 3 & 6 & 9} = \pmatrix{14 & 32 & 50}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I personally like to think of it this way:

Let $v=(v_1 , v_2, \dots, v_m)$ be a row vector,  and let $A_1, A_2 \dots ,A_m$ denote the rows of $A$. The product $vA$ is the linear combination of the rows of $A$ weighted by the components of $v$. That is,

$vA= v_1  A_1 +v_2  A_2 + \dots +v_m  A_m$

For a little more geometric interpretation, I personally like to think of the components of $v$ as giving "coordinates" and the rows of $A$ as giving the direction of my axes.

I'm Happy to explain anything further. Hope this helps.

Comment: I think of $Av$ in a very similar way... If you want a great resource check out [link] https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kjBOesZCoqc&list=PLZHQObOWTQDPD3MizzM2xVFitgF8hE_ab ... It is a really nice refresher and great for visual learners.